# Where can I find labeled pictures for tests of empathy?

Tags: empathy

**QUESTION:**

Where can I find labeled pictures to reproduce empathy measurement tests?

**CONTEXT:**

[Galynsky et al.](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17201789/) showed that empathy, as measured by recognizing emotions from faces, is reduced in subjects after reminiscing a past event when the subject was in a situation of power over another subject, and being put in a situation of high power (deciding how to distribute tombola coupons).

Joanna Macy in her book "[Active Hope](https://www.amazon.com/Active-Hope-revised-without-Going/)" distinguishes the notions of "power over" (e.g. a employer over their employee) and "power with" (e.g. two collaborators).

I would be interested in replicating the study from [Galynsky et al.](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/17201789/) (and hence further validate it), and in extending it by including examples of "power over" and "power with" (and hence refine their results).

Being a beginner in psychology (aiming for Psycho Informatics, the automation of Psychological processes and experiments), I am not sure exactly the process to replicate (and extend) such an experiment. I was assuming that all the information required to replicate the results should be made public (reproducibility being central to the research process), but it is not included in the paper, and the authors of the original study failed to answer me :(

Comment: Assuming the methods section doesn't say something like "we used this specific set of images available from XYZ", you could look for professional websites by the authors where they may have posted something like this, otherwise you're stuck with just trying to contact the authors to ask. Good luck.